# How can I determine if a test passed or failed by examining the Item object passed to the pytest_runtest_teardown?

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest allows you to hook into the teardown phase for each test by implementing a function called `pytest_runtest_teardown` in a plugin:

```
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    pass
```

Is there an attribute or method on `item` that I can use to determine whether the test that just finished running passed or failed? I couldn't find any documentation for `pytest.Item` and hunting through the source code and playing around in `ipdb` didn't reveal anything obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may also consider call.excinfo in pytest_runtest_makereport:

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    if call.when == 'setup':
        print('Called after setup for test case is executed.')
    if call.when == 'call':
        print('Called after test case is executed.')
        print('-->{}<--'.format(call.excinfo)) 
    if call.when == 'teardown':
        print('Called after teardown for test case is executed.')
```

The call object contains a whole bunch of additional information (test start time, stop time, etc.).

Refer: 
http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/runner.html

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    when = call.when
    duration = call.stop-call.start
    keywords = dict([(x,1) for x in item.keywords])
    excinfo = call.excinfo
    sections = []
    if not call.excinfo:
        outcome = "passed"
        longrepr = None
    else:
        if not isinstance(excinfo, ExceptionInfo):
            outcome = "failed"
            longrepr = excinfo
        elif excinfo.errisinstance(pytest.skip.Exception):
            outcome = "skipped"
            r = excinfo._getreprcrash()
            longrepr = (str(r.path), r.lineno, r.message)
        else:
            outcome = "failed"
            if call.when == "call":
                longrepr = item.repr_failure(excinfo)
            else: # exception in setup or teardown
                longrepr = item._repr_failure_py(excinfo,
                                            style=item.config.option.tbstyle)
    for rwhen, key, content in item._report_sections:
        sections.append(("Captured %s %s" %(key, rwhen), content))
    return TestReport(item.nodeid, item.location,
                      keywords, outcome, longrepr, when,
                      sections, duration)
```

Comment: How do you handle rerun test, If you have added rerun then same test case will first show as fail and then if got passed in second run then in pass too.
Or if got failed in second run then for 1 test case it will show fail count as 2.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Node` class](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.main.Node) don't have any information regarding the status of the last test, however we do have the status of the total number of failed tests (in `item.session.testsfailed`), and we can use it:

1. We can add a new member to the `item.session` object (not so nice, but you gotta love python!). This member will save the status of the last `testsfailed` - `item.session.last_testsfailed_status`.
2. If `testsfailed` > `last_testsfailed_status` - the last test the run just failed.

---

```
import pytest
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level='INFO',
    handlers=(
        logging.StreamHandler(),
        logging.FileHandler('log.txt')
    )
)

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    outcome = yield

    if not hasattr(item.session, 'last_testsfailed_status'):
        item.session.last_testsfailed_status = 0

    if item.session.testsfailed and item.session.testsfailed > item.session.last_testsfailed_status:
        logging.info('Last test failed')

    item.session.last_testsfailed_status = item.session.testsfailed
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I was also struggling to get the Test Status, so that I can use it to make a custom report.
But, after further analysis of pytest_runtest_makereport hook function, I was able to see various attributes of 3 params (item, call, and report).
Let me just list some of it out:

1. Call:

   - excinfo (this further drills down to carry traceback if any)
   - start (start time of the test in float value since epoch time)
   - stop (stop time of the test in float value since epoch time)
   - when (can take values - setup, call, teardown)
2. item:

   - _fixtureinfo (contains info abt any fixtures you have used)
   - nodeid (the test_name assumed by pytest)
   - cls (contains the class info of test, by info I mean the variables which were declared and accessed in the class of test)
   - funcargs (what parameters you have passed to your test along with its values)
3. report:

   - outcome (this carries the test status)
   - longrepr (contains the failure info including the traceback)
   - when (can take values - setup, call, teardown. please note that depending on its value the report will carry the values)

FYI: there are other attributes for all the above 3 params, I have mentioned in few.
Below is the code snipped depicting, of how I have hooked the function and used.

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
report = __multicall__.execute()

if (call.when == "call") and hasattr(item, '_failed_expect'):
    report.outcome = "failed"
    summary = 'Failed Expectations:%s' % len(item._failed_expect)
    item._failed_expect.append(summary)
    report.longrepr = str(report.longrepr) + '\n' + ('\n'.join(item._failed_expect))

if call.when == "call":
    ExTest.name = item.nodeid
    func_args = item.funcargs
    ExTest.parameters_used = dict((k, v) for k, v in func_args.items() if v and not hasattr(v, '__dict__'))
    # [(k, v) for k, v in func_args.items() if v and not hasattr(v, '__dict__')]
    t = datetime.fromtimestamp(call.start)
    ExTest.start_timestamp = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d::%I:%M:%S %p')
    ExTest.test_status = report.outcome
    # TODO Get traceback info (call.excinfo.traceback)  
    return report
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook wrappers are the way to go - allow all the default hooks to run & then look at their results.

Below example shows 2 methods for detecting whether a test has failed (add it to your `conftest.py`)

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # Because this is a hookwrapper, calling `yield` lets the actual hooks run & returns a `_Result`
    result = yield
    # Get the actual `TestReport` which the hook(s) returned, having done the hard work for you
    report = result.get_result()

    # Method 1: `report.longrepr` is either None or a failure representation
    if report.longrepr:
        logging.error('FAILED: %s', report.longrepr)
    else:
        logging.info('Did not fail...')

    # Method 2: `report.outcome` is always one of ['passed', 'failed', 'skipped'] 
    if report.outcome == 'failed':
        logging.error('FAILED: %s', report.longrepr)
    elif report.outcome == 'skipped':
        logging.info('Skipped')
    else:  # report.outcome == 'passed'
        logging.info('Passed')
```

See [`TestReport`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.runner.TestReport) documentation for details of `longrepr` and `outcome`

(It doesn't use `pytest_runtest_teardown` as the OP requested but it does easily let you check for failure)

Comment: How do you handle rerun test, If you have added rerun then same test case will first show as fail and then if got passed in second run then in pass too. Or if got failed in second run then for 1 test case it will show fail count as 2

Comment: The above doesn't modify any pytest state, it just outputs log lines to aid debugging from a log file after the fact - it will presumably log 'FAILED' the first time and 'Passed' on the retry

Comment: I agree, But thats what i want to know if there is a way to avoid that and show only pass result.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732689/how-to-handle-rerun-in-pytest-with-pytest-runtest-makereport-fixture