# Is there a way to have the Python debugger always pause before exiting?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I can set breakpoints, but often I just want to look at some variables after I run a test.

Is there a way to debug a pytest test in vscode and just have it always pause before exiting? Without me setting break points or writing pause statements?

Comment: This sounds like a request for new functions, but breakpoints can fully meet this requirement. It seems pointless to deliberately discard breakpoints. You can submit a feature request on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) to solicit votes if you hope.

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvote. While my desired behavior might be peculiar I'm asking a specific question about how to accomplish a specific goal with a specific language, framework and tool. Perhaps its not vscode specific though so I guess that tag could probably be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set specific final actions from within `pytest` tearDown methods:

```py
pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem)

pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call)

pytest_runtest_logreport(report)

pytest_exception_interact(call, report)
```

(More info on that here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html)

These methods can exist in a `conftest.py` file.

Eg:

```py
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item):
    ...
    # Do something after every test that runs.
```

This existing Stack Overflow solution can give you a good start on possible implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40446593/7058266

From there, you can have your tests do whatever you want... print variables, use breakpoints, etc.

Comment: So I could throw a `breakpoint()` statement under `pytest_runtest_teardown` in conftest.py? Could I parameterize this so it only does this if I run pytest with a custom param set?

Comment: Yes, you can throw a ``breakpoint()`` in there. Use an ``if`` statement for it to occur under specific conditions. There are different options for accessing the variables for that. ``item`` is passed, so you can use what's in there... or you can get the value from a global or import.